# How can I dynamically update Accordion Tab with Info Mark

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I need to update the accordion tab with an info mark (!) to notify the user about some changes, and then make the mark go away when the user clicks on the tab.

As an example based on the image below, lets say there is some change in the application, at this point I want to show the red info mark as shown in the 'Apples' accordion tab below. Once the user clicks on the 'Apples' accordion tab, the mark should disappear.

This is very standard use case to notify users of changes that have happened. How do I implement this change?

[image]

Comment: Use `TitledPane.setGraphic(...)`.

Comment: @James_D - thank you!